# Order by count() on specific attribute Core Data

Tags: sql, core-data, count, core-data-migration

So I am basically trying to select the entire object, for the first 10 objects ordered by the # of occurrences of a specific attribute in a many-to-one relationship.

Essentially in the one table I have an 'id' attribute that maps to another table.  There can be any number of reoccurring id's and I want to get the object for whichever 10 occur most often.

I can handle that fine in sql but don't know how to implement the equivelent in core data?

Heres what I got in sql:

```
SELECT *, count(id) AS count FROM ____ ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Thanks a lot for all the help everyone! It's much appreciated

Comment: Is it "core date" (in title) or "core data" (in question)? - there's a spelling mistake somewhere

Comment: core data.... well thats embarrassing

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this. I am current Trying to do this with an `orderItem --> product` setup. I need to get the top 5 products. Luckily my products list is relatively short so I could do a standard groupBy and sort them myself but a true query would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding whether I understand the question correctly, or what your expected behavior is going to be re: sorting of the results. For example, if count("some_specific_id") > 10, then which 10 objects do you want back? Does it matter?

That question aside, I'm not sure you're going to be able to do this easily or efficiently.

Given (as I understand it):

1. You have a relationship between Entities Foo and Bar. Foo.bar is a to-one relationship with Bar, and Bar.foo is a to-many relationship with Foo.
2. You want 10 Foo objects, the ones that match your SQL statement.

Here's one way to approach it:

1. Fetch all of your Bar entities.
2. Sort that array by "foo.@count", descending.
3. Start enumerating over the sorted Bar array, and for each object, grab the Foo objects from its NSSet property named foo, until you have 10 of them.

I wasn't able to find any way through Apple's documentation to do this without fetching all of the Bar entities. With more information about your particular Entities you might be able to figure something smarter out. Other suggestions floating around said that if you really want to know the count of objects on the Bar->Foo relationship, maintain that in a separate property. Then you could do a fetch of Bar sorted by fooCount, and limited to 10, since that would be the upper limit needed to find 10 Foo objects.